# Start bezier curve animation (turntable) from negative frame

Tags: animation

I have a liquid domain baked in frame 0-50. I've added a turntable animation which I want to end with the liquid animation. I've set `Allow negative frames` in animation settings. However I can't enter my desired `-200` negative start frame, it remains 0. Neither do I have any keyframes I could move in the dopesheet as suggested in some answers.
[image: Text]

Answer (score 1):

you cannot add a negative start frame here:

[image]

But you can enter a negative start frame in your fluid simulation:

[image]

But of course you have to do that before you bake your animation.

But what you can do, instead of baking your simulation again, you can just move your turntable animation to your desired place by selecting your turntable, go in the timetable, tap A to select all and then move your animation as you want it - even to negative frames.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have anything to select nor move in the timetable https://i.imgur.com/ARx4nRp.png

Comment: So how do you animate your turntable? With shape keys?

Comment: Add a curve (select circle), select camera, shift+select path, ctrl p, follow path